# using split to store values and find the average of numbers

Tags: python, list

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVM73.jpg)

```
numbers = int(input("enter 3 numbers:"))
a, b, c = numbers.split()
average = (a+b+c)/3
print(average)
```

> if there is any better way of doing this please do suggest

Comment: Your provided code block and the code in the screenshot do not match.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you convert the `numbers` to `int` and then do `.split()`:

1. You cannot convert string e.g. `1 2 3` to int
2. Even if you have an integer, it doesn't have `.split()` method

The correct steps are split the string first, then convert to integers:

```py
a, b, c = map(int, input("enter 3 numbers: ").split())
average = (a + b + c) / 3
print(average)
```

Prints (for example):

```
enter 3 numbers: 1 2 3
2.0
```

---

EDIT: For arbitrary numbers (not just 3):

```py
lst = list(map(int, input("enter numbers: ").split()))
average = sum(lst) / len(lst)
print(average)
```

Answer (score 1):

input number as `string` then `split` them and map `int` for each one , then convert them to `list` and use `numpy.mean` for getting `average`.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful. Also importing `numpy` for this seems a bit overkill.

Comment: oh thats one line code thanks,but do you know what error i made above?

Comment: @AmalSebastian which error for which code? where is your code that gets an error?

Answer (score 0):

Using map will be better:

```
a, b, c = map(int, input("enter 3 numbers: ").split())
average = (a+b+c)/3
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce line of codes

```
num1, num2, num3 = int(input("Enter three numbers comma separated:" ) ).split(', ') 
print((num1+num2+num3)/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean
print(mean(map(int, input("enter 3 numbers: ").split())))
```